# Windows 10 hangs after trying to download/upload something in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, freeze

I upgraded to Windows 10 recently (Build 10586 currently). Since then I have been having problems with Chrome: whenever I try to save or upload a file, the computer freezes within moments of displaying the Select File dialog.

If it gives any more info, the mouse starts lagging about half a second after the Select File dialog appears and then completely freezes. Mouse sometimes moves for a while but nothing on the screen responds, even the taskbar doesn't make hover animations.

This has happened regularly in both regular Chrome and Chrome Canary and occasionally on Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Normally the computer becomes completely unrecoverable other than a hard reboot. Sending the computer to sleep works, but it won't resume.

Today I managed to regain functionality by turning off Wifi and Bluetooth through the hardware button, waiting a while, (mouse started responding a bit although in a laggy manner), trying to press the close button on Chrome, pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del (this worked), opening Task Manager and closing Chrome and stopping the SuperFetch service which was making disk usage a constant 100%.

After about 10 seconds, everything became normal.

Today's problem started when I tried to upload two pictures to Facebook.

Chrome has been updating automatically since this started so I don't think its a update issue.
I had previously read somewhere that it was probably caused by Avast but today's issue occurred after I already uninstalled Avast.

Can anyone please give me some idea what could have caused this and how to prevent this? I'll post updates as I try to crash it again under different circumstances.

EDIT: Tried to trigger another freeze by restarting SuperFetch, turning Wifi and Bluetooth back on and again trying to upload the same pictures to Facebook. No freeze triggered. Tried again by downloading pictures from various sources. Still no freeze. Will try again after a reboot.

Comment: If you manually configure a minimal boot configuration does this behavior still exhibit itself?

Comment: My startup configuration has no more than the following: AMD Catalyst Control Center, Trackpad, Bluetooth, Accelerometer, Audio drivers. I'll check once after disabling these too.

Also, I edited the question to include info about an attempt to re-trigger the freeze.